# Can Renderscript programmatically force code to run on CPU?

Tags: android, renderscript

By using the adb tools, we can force Renderscript code to run on CPU before the program launches, as mentioned in [Forcing Renderscript to run on CPU or GPU (Atleast for performance tuning purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753935/forcing-renderscript-to-run-on-cpu-or-gpu-atleast-for-performance-tuning-purpos). I'm wondering if there's a switch to programmatically force code to run on CPU in code? Thank you!

Comment: What result are you looking to achieve by forcing to the CPU?  Latency, power, leave GPU for graphics, other ?

Comment: @R.JasonSams Thanks a lot for the reply. There are certain situations I might need to do this. The situations are listed but not limited as follows. 1. leave GPU for graphics; 2. certain algorithms are more suitable to run on multi-core CPU than on GPU, if can't be satisfactorily optimized for GPU, I'd like to let it to run on CPU for speed; 3. There are certain renderscript functions are very slow in some GPU, e.g. I tried the pow() function and its variants on a Qualcomm Adreno 330 GPU (in Nexus 5), and turned this function is extremely slow in the current implementation.

Comment: cont. Once such issue can't be avoided (in pow() case, I can avoid it by using other functions, it may not be the case for others), I tend to manually switch the code to CPU. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Actually I'm also interested in enforcing CPU execution instead of GPU. The reason is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50548979/15139. Is there a way to programmatically enforce it similar to enabling `debug.rs.default-CPU-driver` flag?