# What is best value for "Rendercript Optim Level"?

Tags: android-studio, build, renderscript

**Android Studio --> Open Module Settings --> Build Types --> Renderscript Optim Level** *--> (3)* // by default

(3) or something else? Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use the default "optim" level 3.

[What is “Rendercript Optim Level”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025223/what-is-rendercript-optim-level/43220327)

[Where is the RenderScript source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294624/where-is-the-renderscript-source-code)