# What is “Rendercript Optim Level”?

Tags: android-studio, build, renderscript

**Android Studio --> Open Module Settings --> Build Types --> Renderscript Optim Level** *--> (3)* // by default

What is "Rendercript Optim Level" best value?

Comment: Clearly it's *3*, unless you have a specific reason to change it. If you don't know what it is or what it means, you don't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use the default "optim" level 3.

In the renderscript source, level 3 corresponds to the value
[`llvm::CodeGenOpt::Aggressive`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm_1_1CodeGenOpt.html) in the [slang](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/compile/slang/+/master/rs_cc_options.cpp#286) compiler.

It's the argument that sets the level of optimization slang uses to compile the `.rs` file into the intermediate bitcode (`.bc`) file that get shipped with your app.

Interestingly, the optim level is included in the script's `.bc` file, but [ignored](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/compile/libbcc/+/master/lib/RSCompilerDriver.cpp#410) by the bcc compiler that finishes preparing the script on the device. It just discards the value and sets it to `llvm::CodeGenOpt::Aggressive` no matter what.

sources:

[Where is the RenderScript source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294624/where-is-the-renderscript-source-code)